# How to output thumbnail twice in a loop

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

ok I have a portfolio page. & I have two question:

number 1: Every portfolio item has thumbnail attached. what I want is to print out the first thumbnail from the first post twice. One at the beginning & other at the ending. like: image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4 & image_1 again.

number 2: All my images have some id, like: id="photo_46", id="photo_47", id="photo_48" & so on... I want my last thumbnail(the thumbnail which I have repeated in the first stage at the end of the loop) to not have this id.

my code is:

```
<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'dsc');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php $extraFirstClass = $loop->current_post == '0' ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : ''; ?>

<?php 
$attributes = array(
    "class" => "main-image portfolio " . $extraFirstClass,
    "id" => "photo_{$post->ID}",
);
the_post_thumbnail("portfolio_thumb", $attributes);
?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php rewind_posts(); ?> 


    <div class="portfolio-box">
        <h5>Portfolio</h5>
        <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>              
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I solve this two problem?
A live exmaple of what I'm trying to accomplish can be find here: http://kzarchitecture.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 1):

You can `rewind_posts()` then just call `$loop->the_post()` once outside of the `while` loop, output the thumbnail, and `rewind_posts()` again to output the `ul` list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not very good with php, can you modify my code?